# My Content tab in share point is giving an error,when clicked

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

when i click on the my content tab of my share point site,its giving a "this webpage cannot is found" error.Somebody please help me. My colleagues are not getting this error

Answer (score 0):

Please get in touch with your SharePoint administrator. It looks as if your MySite is broken. This may be due to an error in the User Profile Service. There is not much you can do unless you are an administrator and can check the user profiles in the UPS.